# Connecting to MongoDB Atlas with TypeOrm?

Tags: mongodb, typeorm, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to Mongodb Atlas with TypeOrm.

Here is my `ormconfig.json` :

```
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "host": "cluster0-****.mongodb.net",
  "port": 27017,
  "username": "testUser",
  "password": "******",
  "database": "test",
  "useNewUrlParser": true,
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": ["src/entity/*.*"]
}
```

And then when I try to `createConnection()` is get this error :
`(node:10392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-****.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0-****.mongodb.net cluster0-****.mongodb.net:27017]`

Actually I can not find any information on how to do this.

Is my port right ? And if it is not where can I found it ? Where can I find my database name on Atlas ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok I solved it by doing :

```
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "url": "mongodb+srv://testUser:<password>@cluster0-****.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
  "useNewUrlParser": true,
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": ["src/entity/*.*"]
}
```

I don't really know what was the issue with the "field by field" config but it seems to work fine by passing the url.

Answer (score 5):

The TYPEORM documentation is not so clear on mongodb connection issues, and maybe not updated frequently with. So I'm dropping this here for future readers.

1. You need to make sure that your IP is whitelisted. (You can do so by going to `project => network access [tab] => IP whitelist [tab]` and [add your ip address](https://www.google.com/search?q=my%20ip%20address) or use `0.0.0.0`.
2. Enable SSL for your connection by setting `ssl:true` in your orm config file.
3. Don't forget to add your authentication database using `authSource:admin`.

Below is an example of my `.env` file

```sh
TYPEORM_CONNECTION=mongodb
TYPEORM_HOST=cluster0-shard-00-02-xxxxx.mongodb.net
TYPEORM_PORT=27017
TYPEORM_USERNAME=root
TYPEORM_PASSWORD=password
TYPEORM_DATABASE=mydatabase
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE=true
TYPEORM_LOGGING=true
TYPEORM_ENTITIES=./dist/**/*.entity.js
TYPEORM_DRIVER_EXTRA={"ssl":true, "authSource": "admin"}
```

Comment: thank you! I got stuck for 1 hour not being able to login, until I found out that `ssl` and authSource options were necessary.